# Is there a limit on Stream threads (num.stream.threads ) number to be used for kafka streams when we are using nested aggregations

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My kafka stream application does not start when I have a stream threads count more then 110.
Is there a limit on stream threads configurations for kafka streams.

There is a use case were we wanted to use nested aggregations using kafka streams DSL(in the tunes of 50 to 100 nested aggregations each aggregation resulting in a repartitioned topic). As per some of the reading ideal stream threads configurations should be equal to number of partitions. So say when I have 20 aggregations with source topic having 10 partition there will be overall 210 partitions including the repartitioned topic partitions so I set the stream threads to 210, with this my application does not startup.(Even tried horizontally scaling my application to say 10 instance with 21 stream threads each with this as well I am facing the same issue)
Kafka verion - 1.1.1
Kafka streams version - 2.2

Comment: Did you run the 10 instances with 21 stream threads on the same machine or on 10 different machines?

Comment: ` As per some of the reading ideal stream threads configurations should be equal to number of partitions.` -- That sounds wrong. It depends on your hardware how many thread you should start per instance -- a rule of thumb is one thread per core. If that is not sufficient, you need to scale out adding new instanced to get more cores (and implicitly more threads for the overall application).